# Check for perfect number using boolean

Tags: java, boolean, perfect-numbers

I have problem with my Java coding to find the perfect number using boolean method. I want to print out like this:
Example :
‘6 is a perfect number. 6 is the sum of  1, 2, 3’
Otherwise :
‘9 is not a perfect number’

But I don't know how to make the coding for "6 is the sum of 1, 2, 3". Can anyone help me?
Here is my coding :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class trial
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner perfect = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter any integer number : ");
        int n = perfect.nextInt();

        if(isPerfectNumber(n))
        {
            System.out.println(n+" is a perfect number");

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(n+" is not a perfect number");
        }
    }

    public static boolean isPerfectNumber(int n)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i=1; i<n; i++)
        {
            if (n%i == 0)
            {
                sum = sum + i;
            }
        }
        if (sum == n)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you already *know* how to get the factors of the number, as per the `if (n%i == 0)` line.

So, hint only since this is almost certainly class work.

At the same point you add the factor to the sum, you should add it to a list of some description and have that made available to the calling function.

One possibility would be to return a list, the second and subsequent elements being all the factors of the given number, and the first element being the sum of those.

So, for `6`, you would get the list `{6, 1, 2, 3}`, `12` would give you `{16, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6}`, and `7` would give you `{7, 1}`.

That way, you simply have to check the original number against the first element and, if they're equal, print out the other elements. In other words, pseudo-code such as:

```
input num
factorList = getFactorList(num)
if factorList[0] == num:
    print num, " is perfect, factors are:"
    for idx = 1 to factorList.size() - 1 inclusive:
        print " ", factorList[idx]
    println "."
else:
    println num, " is not perfect."
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd change `isPerfectNumber` to return a `List` of the factors that make `n` or `null` if it's not a perfect number. Then you have a single result that both contains factors and can be used to determine if `n` is perfect:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner perfect = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter any integer number : ");
    int n = perfect.nextInt();

    List<Integer> factors = getPerfectFactors(n);
    if (factors != null) {
        System.out.println
            (n + " is a perfect number. It's the sum of" +
             factors.stream()
                    .map(String::valueOf)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
    } else {
        System.out.println(n+" is not a perfect number");
    }
}

public static List<Ingeger> getPerfectFactors(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    List<Ingeger> factors = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0)  {
            sum += i;
            factors.add(i);
        }
        if (sum > n) { // Early return optimization, not material to the solution
            return null;
        }
    }
    if (sum == n) {
        return factors;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: but I have to use the boolean method to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Well in the for loop if condition if modulus is true then you know the `i` has to be kept in track somehow.

So I would
declare an arraylist of integers to keep track of summation numbers.

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Then

```
public static boolean isPerfectNumber(int n)
{
        int sum = 0;            
        for (int i=1; i<n; i++)
        {
            if (n%i == 0)
            {
                numbs.add(i);  //here keep track of those summation numbers
                sum = sum + i;
            }
        }
        if (sum == n)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
}
```

Now while printing you can do like

```
System.out.println(n + " is a perfect number. " + n + " is sum of " + StringUtils.join(numbs, ","));
```

Don't forget to import StringUtils: `import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils commons-lang3` library.

Comment: I did what are you suggest me to do but why do I still found some errors in my programs? The code become like this :

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
public class test
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  ArrayList<Integer> numbs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  Scanner perfect = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Enter any integer number : ");
  int n = perfect.nextInt();
  
  if(isPerfectNumber(n))
  {
   System.out.println(n+" is a perfect number");
   System.out.println(n+" is the sum of " + StringUtils.join(numbs, ","));
  }
  else
  {
  System.out.println(n+" is not a perfect number");
  }
 }

Comment: public static boolean isPerfectNumber(int n)
 {
  int sum = 0;
  for (int i=1; i<n; i++)
  {
   if (n%i == 0)
   {
    numbs.add(i);
    sum = sum + i;
   }
  }
  if (sum == n)
  {
   return true;
  }
  else
  {
   return false;
  }
 }
}

Comment: I would say you to debug code step by step.also always update your original question. Don't write code in comments box.

Comment: Would you pleasewrite the complete code for me? Because I don't understand what do you mean, since I'm just beginner programmer